# Share a session between two web applications in device

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have more than one applications. I want to be able to share a session between them using cookie_store.

Application A:

```
before_filter :authenticate_from!

def authenticate_from!
    unless session['warden.user.user.key'].nil?
        @user=User.find_or_initialize_by_id(ky[1])
        sign_in @user
    end
end
```

It can work, but application B session can not be identified.
What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done, but both of these applications will need to have a common subdomain and the `secret_token` value in your configuration will have to be identical.

For instance, you can have `app1.example.com` and `app2.example.com` so long as the cookie is assigned to `.example.com`.

The options for this are stored in `config/initializers/session_store.rb` and `config/initializers/secret_token.rb`.

As a note, ensure that your secret token value is as long and random as in a default install. Don't just switch to something short and convenient.

Comment: Thank you very much in accordance with the program , I was successful