# Share session between two domains which are using the same source code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I have two domains which are pointed to the same rails application in a server. I logged in as a **`#User1`** via domain1 and the same session should be used by the domain2 in the same browser. But, I don't know how to do this?

I got the below **#SE** link, which is describing the session sharing between two apps. In my case I want to share the session app it self. Pls help.

[Share a session between two web applications in device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146716/share-a-session-between-two-web-applications-in-device)

Comment: The question you linked is still relevant for your situation. From the user's browser point of view, if the app is served from two different domains, they're in fact two different apps. Please indicate if your two domains share a higher level domain (like domain1.example.com and domain2.example.com) or not.

Comment: No. The domain names are completely different. (example1.com and example2.com).

Comment: Then it's going to be tricky. See if this other question gets you started: http://stackoverflow.com/q/377137/4035338